# Filter XSS in plain text and HTML

Tags: php, xss

I have my own function called xss which return cleaned text. I want to know, if it is enough, or I have some bug there

```
function xss($str,$html = false)
{
  if($html){
    //HTML Purfier called here
  }else{
    return str_replace(array('&','"',"'",'<','>'), array('&amp;','&quot;','&#39;','&lt;','&gt;'), $str);
  }
}
```

I don't want to use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) because it delete all tags. I want to leave them, but replace by the save entity. Is this save when replace these characters?

Comment: For the second part: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Thanks, but it will be enough, right? I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account some other characters that might be problematic. For example ':' and ';'. Imagine that you return the text inside a tag attribute (like an href), then the attacker could use something like 'http://yoursite.com/blah/?parameter=javascript:alert(String.fromCharCode(65))' and that would be reflected as:

```
...
<a href="javascript:alert(String.fromCharCode(65))">
...
```

Or he could use ';' to start a new line inside a script if anything gets reflected there. Try to cover all possible problematic characters.